# Database for monthly schedule and appointments

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-relations

I am trying to create a small system with appointments between doctors and patients. Here is my database(until now). I have two questions:
1) When the user logins to the application how I define if he is an admin, patient or doctor?
2)The main question...I want the doctor, when he logins, to set up his monthly schedule(The days and hours he is free) and the patient when he logins to search for a doctor, see his schedule and make an appointment. i cant think of how to implement this "monthly schedule" of the doctor. Maybe it will be a table linked with foreign key to the doctor table like the speciality table? But how do i actually make a schedule?

If you see anything wrong in my database until now feel free to let me know.
Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
)


CREATE TABLE `admin` (
  `user_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`)
)


CREATE TABLE `patient` (
  `user_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `sin` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,    //social insurance number
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`)
)


CREATE TABLE `speciality` (
  `speciality_id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `speciality_name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`speciality_id`)
)


CREATE TABLE `doctor` (
  `user_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `speciality_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`user_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`speciality_id`) REFERENCES `speciality` (`speciality_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `appointment` (
  `doctor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `patient_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`doctor_id`,`patient_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`doctor_id`) REFERENCES `doctor` (`user_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES `patient` (`user_id`)
)
```

Here is the [relation schema.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sblwW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By briefly looking at your schema, it looks good.

A "schedule" is just the "appointment" table, but you will need to add a start time and an end time to it.

A `SELECT` on that table `WHERE doctor_id = X AND start_time >= first-day-of-the-month AND end_time < first-day-of-next-month` gives you doctor X's schedule.

***EDIT***

For determining whether the user is an admin, patient or doctor, you have a number of options.

- Option #1: introduce a "user type" with possible values: `"ADMIN", "PATIENT", "DOCTOR"`.
- Option #2: use a query to determine whether the `user_id` of the `user` can be found in the `admin`, `patient`, or `doctor` tables.
- Option #3: (my favorite) add three foreign keys to the `user` table: `admin_id`, `patient_id`, and `doctor_id`, only one of which may be non-null.

The advantage of the last approach is that it maintains the relational nature of your schema: the user row is related to the (admin, patient or doctor) row, and the database can enforce referential integrity, meaning that if the `patient_id` field is non-null, then the database will make sure that the value of this field does in fact correspond to one of the `user_id` values in the `patient` table.

Comment: okay thanks, now i get it!... what about my first question? :)

Comment: @GiannisSavvidis I amended my answer.